# Index getting currupt ocationally, Have to Delete and Re-index every day

Tags: search

I'm using [Apache solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and some related sub modules for my search. Something mess-up in my search index all the time. Some times when I search for some keywords my search result page is empty, But I know there should be results for these keywords. Every time when I come across with this issue, I have to delete the search & solr index and re-index again. Then it'll fix, but again in a few days it'll mess-up the search. At-least is there a way to make this process automatically? I mean Delete and Re-index once a day, something like that.

Comment: Do you have configured solr in a way that only your server has access to it? By default solt is open to everybody. Someone could be messing with tour index.

Comment: It's a good point. I just configured it with no extra settings, I have no idea how to configure it to access only my server. can you give me a kick start on this?

Comment: I do not have the documentation at hand right now, but there is plenty of documentation on Drupal.org. just search for the solr installation manual there, I am pretty sure it is in there.